# IPython notebook automatic code completion dropdown and tool tip

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a setting or plugin for IPython notebook to have the code completion drop down automatically show up when you type the "." character?

Similarly, is there a setting to have the tool tips automatically update based on where your cursor is?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743249/ipython-auto-complete-active-constantly